# Selection In UITableView Causes Rows to Disappear Instead of Calling Delegate's tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) (Swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a few small table views.  When a row is tapped, I just want it to show a little checkmark, so in the TableView's datasource I added this method:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  print("Did Select Row at \(indexPath.row)")
  tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

Pretty simple, but when a selection is made in the tableView all of the table's contents disappear, and no checkmark is made.  I explicitly called the didSelectRowAt function, and it worked fine (a little checkmark showed up in the cell and it printed the print statement).

Just wondering if anyone has an explanation for this strange behavior.  Here is the full definition of the Delegate/DataSource (I did not use a controller because it is not the main target of the app).

```
public class TableController : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, 
 UITableViewDelegate {
   private var data : [String]
   private var height : CGFloat


   init(_ data : [String], cellHeight : CGFloat) {
     self.data = data
     self.height = cellHeight
   }

  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
  section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
  }

  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("-cell for row at \(indexPath.row) \n")
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel!.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
 }

  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Did Select Row at \(indexPath.row)")
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the code you show is causing the problems. Just try to comment out `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark` and see if the rows still disappear.